# Why are SwiftUI bottom-toolbar items spaced haphazardly?

Tags: swiftui

I'm mystified at why one toolbar item is shoved off to the right, and then two others are bunched up on the left. The items are all simple buttons declared identically, as follows:

```
NavigationView
{
    ZStack  // Work around NavigationView bug where it ignores background color.
    {
        Styles.bgColor.ignoresSafeArea()    // background
        VStack(alignment: .center)
        {
            Text("Welcome, \(userMgr.user.username)!")
        }
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Button("Boot", action: {
                print("& rally!")
            })
        }

        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Button("Start", action: {
                print("& rally!")
            })
        }
        
        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Button("Jump", action: {
                print("how high?")
            })
        }
    }
    .tint(Color.red)
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .font(.custom("Marker Felt", size: 30))
}
```

The result (the text at the top is invisible because it's black):

[image]

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: How do you want them to be placed instead?

Comment: Evenly-spaced, of course. Why would they be spaced irregularly, when they're declared identically? The behavior here defies years of standard behavior of iOS toolbars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen the `bottomBar` placement algorithm documented anywhere, but it does always seem to place the last item at the trailing position, collecting the previous ones at the leading edge.

For many bottom bar uses this can be useful, giving prominence to a single action in a position where a right-handed user's thumb has easy access. This also seems to be the case if you put all your buttons in a `ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar)`.

However, in situations where you want different placement rules, there are a couple of options.

### Use `placement: .status`

This semantic placement will place your controls in the centre of the bottom bar.

```swift
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .status) {
        Button("Boot", action: {
            print("& rally!")
        })
    }

    ToolbarItem(placement: .status) {
        Button("Jump", action: {
            print("how high?")
        })
    }

    ToolbarItem(placement: .status) {
        Button("Start", action: {
            print("& rally!")
        })
    }
}
```

[image: placement: .status]

### Use `ToolbarItemGroup` with `Spacer()` elements

If you want your buttons to be equally spaced out across the bottom bar, then you can use a `ToolbarItemGroup` with a `bottomBar` placement and add your own `Spacer()` elements:

```swift
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
        Button("Boot", action: {
            print("& rally!")
        })

        Spacer()

        Button("Jump", action: {
            print("how high?")
        })

        Spacer()

        Button("Start", action: {
            print("& rally!")
        })
    }
}
```

[image: Grouped and with Spacer elements]

Comment: Thanks. This is some poor design on Apple's part, compounded by bad documentation. For example, Apple doc says: "status: ToolbarItemPlacement
The item represents a change in status for the current context." There's no reason to guess that this is on the bottom. For that, there's only ".bottom". No other options that you can OR with that one to, for example, combine "bottom" with "principal" or whatever. Not to mention that it has been standard to space toolbar buttons evenly for... 15 years?